# How to match file under a specific path but not particular extension using Regex

Tags: regex, apache, nginx

For example, to match all files (not jpg, png, gif) under the path `common`, e.g.

matched:

```
/common/foo.php
/common/foo.doc
```

not matched:

```
/common/foo.jpg
/common/foo.gif
/foo
```

Currently I am using:

```
\/common\/.*^(?:jpg|png|gif)$
```

Comment: @TimN, updated my current solution. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A negative look-behind would be close to your current attempt:

```
\/common\/.*(?<!\.jpg|\.png|\.gif)$
```

This matches everything starting with "/common/", but not ending in ".jpg", ".png" or ".gif".

[Demo](http://regexr.com?32obm)

Answer (score 0):

```
location /common/ {
    # here configuration for not jpg, png, gif

    location ~ \.(?:png|gif|jpg)$ {
        # here configuration for jpg, png, gif
    }
}
```

- [How nginx processes a request](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html)
- [Documentation: location](http://nginx.org/r/location)